# Watir Webdriver - Cucumber - Grid Execution

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have few stories written in Cucumber feature file and i have step definitions for those as well. Right now the **feature files are running sequentially** and  **the execution is taking more time**. I have used Selenium Webdriver grid and i know the set up for the same. **Is there anyway to integrate Grid with Cucumber ?** I am using page Object model in my framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an articles written by [continuousqa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1956588/continuousqa) on his site - http://sdet.us/selenium-grid-with-watir-and-cucumber-browser-automation/ that will provide you with all you need.

Also you can check this gem - [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) for more lightweight solution.